# WPF Complex Hierarchical data template

Tags: c#, wpf, hierarchical-data

I'm looking at a complex structure and I can't seem to find a way to display it...

My situation:

Class: Milestone has 2 lists inside, a list of other submilestones and a list of activities.

So structured could be like:

M1

- Milestones

  - SubMilestone

    - Milestones
    - Activities
  - Submilestone
- Activities

Anybody has any idea's on how to create this? or could boost me into a direction?

**ANSWER to my problem**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Project.TrackList}">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type deto:Track}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FaseList}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TrackType}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type deto:Fase}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MilestoneList}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FaseType}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type deto:Milestone}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MConverter}}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type deto:Activity}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActivityList}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
```

And the converter:

```
public class MilestoneConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var m = value as Milestone;
        CompositeCollection collection = new CompositeCollection();
        collection.Add(new CollectionContainer()
        {
            Collection = m.MilestoneList
        });
        collection.Add(new CollectionContainer()
        {
            Collection = m.ActivityList
        });
        return collection;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) for example. Doing it in Xaml could be bit complicated in terms of referencing the sources, but using a converter should be acceptable in this case:

```
public class MilestoneItemsSourceCreator : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = value as Milestone;
        CompositeCollection collection = new CompositeCollection();
        collection.Add(new CollectionContainer(){ Collection = input.SubMilestones });
        collection.Add(new CollectionContainer(){ Collection = input.Activities });
        return collection;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<vc:MilestoneItemsSourceCreator x:Key="MilestoneItemsSourceCreator"/>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Milestone}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MilestoneItemsSourceCreator}}">
    <!-- DataTemplate -->
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

This might not completely fit your class structures but you did not post those explicitly, some adjustments might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past.

You should display two list controls (ListView/ListBox for example) one above the other one, and bind the second's Data to the first one's selected item.

In your case, it seems you'd need 3 list controls, adapt as you please.

Comment: I feared for that answer... Thanks! Back to the drawing table! :)

Comment: Unfortunately i am not allowed to post the mentioned code, and i don't have it at home anyway. Sorry. Besides, it seems to me that the question was meant pattern-wise, seems like Tom knows how to do it =)